# ASP.Net How to fixed 2 rows header Gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, header, fixed

Before getting in details, I would like to mention that I tried various solutions from stackoverflow and other too. But none suitable in my scenario. So, I provided detailed information.

I have a GridView and I want to make my header fixed, but I can not fix the header because there is 2 rows of header in my GridView.

I already tried to make my header fixed, but I just can make 1 row header fixed with jQuery. I need someone to help me, to fix this problem. Because I really need 2 rows of header.

Comment: Please [edit] to add meaningful code here. Posting a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your problem would probably help you get better answers. Thanks!

Comment: The information you provided is not detailed enough. Please [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/31151794/edit) and add the code of the GridView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use GridViewScroll with jQuery plugin, it's flexible and easy to use.

Here's a sample on how to apply it:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" /> src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.min.js" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/gridviewScroll.min.js" />

 <script type="text/javascript"> 
    $(document).ready(function () { 
        gridviewScroll(); 
    }); 
    function gridviewScroll() { 
        $('#GridView1').gridviewScroll({ 
            width: 700, 
            height: 330, 
            freezesize: 2, 
            arrowsize: 30, 
            headerrowcount: 2 
        }); 
    } 
</script> 

<asp:gridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" />
```

Notice that you can control how many row headers to fix by changing the `headerrowcount` in `gridviewScroll()` function.

For further information please visit http://gridviewscroll.aspcity.idv.tw/

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try this hope it will help you.

Use Script

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Scripts/ScrollableGridPlugin.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <title></title>

    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#<%=GridView1.ClientID %>').Scrollable();
        }
)
</script>
```

GridView Section

```
<Columns>
              <asp:TemplateField >
              <HeaderTemplate>
        <table style="width: 300px" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
  <td>Column 1</td>
  <td>Column 2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Column 1</td>
  <td>Column 2</td>
</tr>
</table>

      </HeaderTemplate> 
                <ItemTemplate>
        <td><%# Eval("Column 1")%></td>
        <td><%# Eval("Column 2")%></td>
      </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
           </Columns>
```

If you observe above code I added jquery-1.4.1.min.js and ScrollableGridPlugin.js script files in header section of code you need to download these script files. By using these files we can manage the gridview header in fixed position.